# How to build console application in debug mode and windows application in release mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

As they do with Sharpdevelop, when you start the solution in `debug` mode, it starts the application and a console (that displays logs). When you start the application in `release` mode it only starts the application.

When I modify the `.prj` file using the Visual Studio Gui, the last configuration overrides the `debug` **and** the `release` mode.

How do I configure Visual Studio to have the same behaviours as the Sharpdevelop solution?

Comment: Is that a Windows Forms app or a console app?

Comment: @marceln WPF application

Comment: Updated answer with a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Visual Studio project keeps application settings organized in three PropertyGroups.  Debug, Release, and a set of options that are independent of the active configuration.  OutputType is in that last one.

The workaround is to simply create the console yourself.  Use the Application.Startup event, like this:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
#if DEBUG
        AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
#endif
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();
}
```

Comment: The idea is great and it works with log4net. Just for the record, I had to call `AllocConsole` before the first log otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Works for WPF application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not have this behavior.

However, for Windows Forms/WPF apps it has the output tool window (menu View/Output to show it). All logs, diagnostic messages and everything debug is displayed there.

For console applications it makes sense that the app will be run in a console (terminal window).

EDIT: If you come to think of it, you could do something like that in VS too.
In the project properties, go to Debug and as Start Action select External Program. There you can enter the path

> %WINDIR%/system32/cmd.exe /k "Path to your debug exe"